# Where are the recorded macros stored in Notepad++?

Tags: file, macros, notepad++, file-location

I have recorded a macro that I want to share with my work colleague.

In what location are these recorded macros saved, so that I can add it to his machine?

If interested, the macro is for taking a list of values and adding quotes and comma so that it can be used in the `WHERE` clause of of an SQL query (`WHERE x IN ('value1','value2','value3')`).

Comment: Wow... I came up with a macro that does exactly that and wanted to export it for almost the same reason and found your post. Goes to show how much of what programmers do is re-inventing the wheel :/ would be nice if notepad++ has a community for sharing macros.

Comment: For those looking to actually program macros (in python): http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/ (available as a plugin from within notepad++'s plugin manager)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

In Windows the macros are saved at `%AppData%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`
(*Windows logo key + E* and *copy&paste* `%AppData%\Notepad++\`)

Or:

- In Windows < 7 (including Win2008/R2) the macros are saved at `C:\Documents and
  Settings\%username%\Application Data\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`
- In Windows 7|8|10
  `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`

*Note:* You will need to close Notepad++ if you have any new macros you want to 'export'.

---

Here is an example:

```
<NotepadPlus>
    <InternalCommands />
    <Macros>
        <Macro name="Trim Trailing and save" Ctrl="no" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="83">
            <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="42024" lParam="0" sParam="" />
            <Action type="2" message="0" wParam="41006" lParam="0" sParam="" />
        </Macro>
        <Macro name="abc" Ctrl="no" Alt="no" Shift="no" Key="0">
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="a" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="b" />
            <Action type="1" message="2170" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="c" />
        </Macro>
    </Macros>
    <UserDefinedCommands>....
```

I added the 'abc' macro as a proof-of-concept.

Comment: I had to close and open notepad++ again to see the changes in the files for a macro I just recorded.

Comment: By the way, you can use %username% instead of [username] and it works automatically when pasted to explorer's address bar.

Comment: I found that I had to edit the shortcuts.xml in a different editor otherwise Notepad++ just overwrote my changes when I closed it... Also you can use `%appdata%` in Explorers address bar to get straight into the Roaming or Application Data directories.

Comment: yes, edit it in another text editor, otherwise Notepad++ keeps overwriting it.

Comment: It's possible to merge several macro in one (the operation will be done one after the other). It's very intuitive: just remove the end macro tags after the first one + the tags introducing the second one, (only the first macro will appear on notepad++). Launch it, and it will launch the operation of the first + the operation of the second macro that has been added to the end of the first). (@Zhaph, I did edit my macro using notepad++, no problem)

Comment: If you use the AppData environment variable, you can specify a single path which will be valid on all versions of Windows, both old and new;

%AppData%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml

Comment: Note: Newly added macros won't reflect until you close Notepad++

Answer (score 39):

For Windows 7 macros are stored at `C:\Users\`*`Username`*`\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`.

Comment: Just deleted some old macros and made a new macro. For me the macros where saved or deleted to shortcuts.xml first **after** saving any/random file in Notepad++, took a while to figure it out.

Comment: Or just use this, which will work in all cases: `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml`

Answer (score 5):

Hit <kbd>F6</kbd>

Insert::

```
npp_open $(PLUGINS_CONFIG_DIR)\..\..\shortcuts.xml
```

Click OK

You now have the file opened in your editor.

---

Before altering things checkout the related docs:

- [Task automation with macros | Notepad++ User Manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/macros/)
- [Configuration Files Details | Notepad++ User Manual](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/config-files/#macros) (section about the <macros> tag)

Comment: The contents of a macro definition can be edited only in the shortcuts.xml file: there is no built-in interface in Notepad++. For more information on the details of how the macros are stored, and the syntax involved, see the [Configuration Files Details: section.](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/config-files/#macros)

Comment: What does [F6] mean to you? In my configuration it does nothing.

Comment: @Wolf It looks like they may be using the NppExec plugi - https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec

Answer (score 4):

On Vista with virtualization on, the file is here. Note that the AppData folder is hidden. Either show hidden folders, or go straight to it by typing **%AppData%** in the address bar of Windows Explorer.

```
C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\shortcuts.xml
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find the `shortcuts.xml` in `AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\` path only when using the default settings. If you have backup configured, you can find and set the path in `Preferences -> Backup -> Backup path`.

When these settings are applied, files in AppData directory won't be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you install Notepad++ on Linux system by wine (In my case desktop Ubuntu 14.04-LTS_X64) the file "shortcuts.xml" is under :

```
$/home/[USER-NAME]/.wine/drive_c/users/[USER-NAME]/My Documents/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Notepad++/shortcuts.xml
```

Thanks to Harrison and all that have suggestions for that isssue.

Answer (score 1):

Notepad++ will forget your macros unless you map them to hotkeys via Settings - Shortcut mapper - Macros before exiting Notepad++ (as per https://superuser.com/questions/332481/how-can-i-add-a-macro-in-notepad.  Tested with Notepad v6.8.3 on Windows7.)

Answer (score 0):

Go to %appdata%\Notepad++ folder.

The macro definitions are held in shortcuts.xml inside the `<Macros>` tag. You can copy the whole file, or copy the  tag and paste it into shortcuts.xml at the other location.
In the latter case, be sure to use another editor, since N++ overwrites shortcuts.xml on exit.