# notepad++ select hyphenated text

Tags: text-editor, notepad++

I could'nt find a solution to a problem that has been hindering the use of notepad++.
When you double click text to highlight that text and others like it, `camelCase` or `under_score` words work great, but when `hyphen-words-are-clicked` this does not treat it as a single word and only highlights the segment between the "-".
**question:** how can you customize notepad++ so that hyphenated words are treated as single words? or does anyone know a text editor that does this?

saw this, but not sure how to implement it: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Word_Customisation

this was really helpful: [Where are the recorded macros stored in Notepad++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431964/where-are-the-recorded-macros-stored-in-notepad)

Comment: It has been a long time since you've asked. Do you still use Notepad++?

Comment: @benny-ben switched over to sublime text

Answer (score 13):

Notepad++ rely on Scintilla for word selection. As caoanan noticed in his answer, Scintilla can be configured with the SCI_SETWORDCHARS variable. You can set this variable in Notepad++ with a simple NppExec script:

1. **Install NppExec**

   - Menu `Plugins -> plugin Manager -> Show Plugin Manager`
   - locate NppExec, check the box and hit Install
2. **Create the script**

   - Menu `Plugins -> NppExec -> Execute ...`
   - write this code (you can add other characters, like .$#@ at the end of the list):

     ```
     NPP_CONSOLE 0
     sci_sendmsg SCI_SETWORDCHARS 0 "CDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-"
     ```
   - hit Save...
   - You can now execute it by pressing OK
3. (optionnal) **Execute when Notepad++ starts**

   - Menu `Plugins -> NppExec -> Advanced Options...`
   - Choose your script in the *Execute this script when Notepad++ starts* drop down

Comment: That works for me but I had to use the following set of characters (not sure why the original didn't work for me:
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_-"

Comment: @Damien I tried but when I move to another file I have to run the script again every time. Is it possible to avoid it?

Comment: How can I mark my answer as deprecated ? Benny solution is way better with the current version of Notepad++

Answer (score 5):

## 2018

I tried with the published solutions but when I move to another file I have to run the script again every time. So I did this way, in the menu:

```
Settings > Preferences > Delimiter
```

select:

- Add you character as part of word

insert hyphen:

```
-
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I met with the same problem when editing Lisp/Scheme source codes with Notepad++.

The cure lies in the underlying Scintilla library (SciLexer.dll).

I've tried in a "blunt" way -- hack the code and rebuild SciLexer.dll.

Note the **'-'** added to the following code

*CharClassify.cxx*

```
void CharClassify::SetDefaultCharClasses(bool includeWordClass) {
    // Initialize all char classes to default values
    for (int ch = 0; ch < 256; ch++) {
        if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n')
            charClass[ch] = ccNewLine;
        else if (ch < 0x20 || ch == ' ')
            charClass[ch] = ccSpace;
        else if (includeWordClass && (ch >= 0x80 || isalnum(ch) || ch == '_' || ch == '-'))
            charClass[ch] = ccWord;
        else
            charClass[ch] = ccPunctuation;
    }
}
```

Or, the "smart" way, as mentioned at [ScintillaDoc.html](http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc.html#SCI_SETWORDCHARS)

```
SCI_SETWORDCHARS(<unused>, const char *characters)
```

> Scintilla has several functions that operate on words, which are
>   defined to be contiguous sequences of characters from a particular set
>   of characters. This message defines which characters are members of
>   that set. The character sets are set to default values before
>   processing this function. For example, if you don't allow '_' in your
>   set of characters use: SCI_SETWORDCHARS(0,abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");

Answer (score 1):

http://sourceforge.net/p/notepad-plus/discussion/1290590/thread/39ba5cd8/

Install Npp_Exec plugin and copy the string from this thread adding the signs you want Npp considers as part of a word.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that option in Notepad++ yet. Since, you've asked about any other text editor that does so, I would recommend you to use [**Sublime Text**](http://www.sublimetext.com/). It's a really cool text editor with lots of smart features. I bet you'll love it. By default, it does not treat the hyphenated words as a single word. But it's way too easy to customize the setting for that. All you need to do is go to `'Preference-> Setting-Default'`, where you'll find the following setting:

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
```

From there, just remove the hyphen and we're done!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to:

- In the Find window, set the text to find to a space
- In the Shortcut Mapper (Main Menu section) assign "Find Next" to Ctrl+Right and "Find Previous" to Ctrl+Left

Now, so long as the search text is only a space, it will effectively be the only delimiter. If you need other delimiters, for instance comma and period, set the Find text to [ ,.].

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have admin rights and no Plugin Mgr, you can install most plugins by downloading a dll/zip file and saving the dll to the 'plugins' sub-folder under your npp install. Then restart npp.

Comment: No, they didn't - everyone assumed anyone else reading the post either would have admin rights, or would know how to install without.  I have fixed that assumption.  I don't have admin rights at work, I'd never used npp before, and I found it quite difficult to find instructions on how to install my first plugin without admin rights.  Indeed I wasn't even sure it was possible.  Anyone without plugin mgr finding this post will be enlightened.