# How do I delete associated symbols when using Notepad++?

Tags: python, notepad++

So lets say I have the argument pyautogui.typewrite(["tab"]) and I want to remove the [] brackets to switch from a key to a string, when I click in-front of the last bracket is shows the first bracket highlighted as-well. How do I delete the first bracket at the same time as the last bracket? There must be a way since both brackets are highlighted before I delete last bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to follow,

- In the `Macro` Menu, click `Start Recording` and perform the below steps
- Select the text you want to remove the square brackets from
- Use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace window
- Use this regex `\[|\]` in the `Find what` field and replace it with an empty string
- Make sure you check the `In selection` box and select `Regular Expression` in Search Mode section
- Click `Replace All`
- Close the Replace window and under the `Macro` Menu, click Stop Recording
- Test the recorded macro using the `Playback` option in the `Macro` Menu
- If satisfied, save the recorded macro by selecting `Save Current Recorded Macro` under `Macro` menu and then assign a shortcut to it

**Note:** `\[|\]` this regex matches either `[` or `]`

Alternatively, you can just edit your [shortcuts.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5431964/10155936) file by adding this to the `Macros` section,

```
<Macro name="test" Ctrl="yes" Alt="yes" Shift="yes" Key="68">
   <Action type="3" message="1700" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
   <Action type="3" message="1601" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="\[|\]" />
   <Action type="3" message="1625" wParam="0" lParam="2" sParam="" />
   <Action type="3" message="1602" wParam="0" lParam="0" sParam="" />
   <Action type="3" message="1702" wParam="0" lParam="896" sParam="" />
   <Action type="3" message="1701" wParam="0" lParam="1609" sParam="" />
</Macro>
```

Here, the name of the macro is `test` and the shortcut assigned is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (ASCII value of D is 68)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was hoping there would be an easier way like holding ctrl + del or something. To be clear, I only want to delete the the opening [ on the specific line I'm working on when I delete the closing ]. Would the macro apply to all lines or only the line I'm working on?

Comment: @KevinBurris, It would apply only to the current selection of text, however you could change that when you are recording the macro

Comment: @KevinBurris, I have added the easier way too, check the second part of the answer

Comment: @KevinBurris, the closest shortcut notepad++ provides for braces are "Go to Matching Brace" and "Select all between matching braces", you can find other shortcuts under Shortcut Manager located under settings

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it.